# Мультиязычный сайт

Tags: php, интернационализация

Я создал сайт для себя. Основной язык - английский. Хочу добавить русский и армянский. Я конечно искал в Google, но подробнее нигде не нашел. Кто может помочь, буду благодарен.

Comment: Должно быть больше конкретики.

Answer (score 10):

Конфиги - это решение на скорую руку для небольшого проекта.

Если мы говорим о выводе текста из PHP, то нормальным способом решения проблемы мультиязычности является использование функции `gettext()`, которая выдает сообщение на языке, в зависимости от выбранной локали.

Список фраз с переводами хранится в скомпилированных файлах словарей. Словари лежат в соответствующих директориях с определенной структурой и названием, например:

```
--- en_US
------ LC_MESSAGES
--------- lang.mo
```

В коде вы пишете только английский вариант фразы, а при вызове функции она автоматически достает из словаря актуальный перевод и выдает его пользователю.

[Описание и примеры](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)
[Справка по gettext](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)

Прелесть этой функции еще и в том, что у нее есть стандартный псевдоним: `_()`, т.е.

```
echo gettext("Hello user!");
//равнозначно:
echo _("Hello user!");
//согласитесь, это лучше чем:
echo $lang['rus']['hello_user'];
```

Утилиты для создания и компиляции словарей доступны бесплатно, см. вики, или погуглите на тему [инструментарий для gettext](http://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+gettext).

Работа со словарем сводится к запуску итилиты, которая прочитает директорию с проектом и создаст заготовку для словаря (*.pot файл), и утилиты, с помощью которой словарь будет редактироваться и компилироваться для конечного использования (*.mo файл).

Answer (score 9):

Какой массив? Зачем база данных??
В файле-конфиге, который инклюдится во все остальные, перед выводом записывается переменная, содержащая название файла-перевода.
например:

Главный файл:

```
<?php

  //объявляем константу содержащую путь до файлов языков
  define('LANGAGE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/language/", false);
  //тоже, путь до шаблона вывода
  define('TEMPLATE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template/", false);

  //получаем переменную языка
  $language = $_GET['lang'];
  //не обязательно получать переменную гет-ом
  //можно брать ее откуда угодно, например - из базы данных, или из сессии

  //загружаем файл перевода
  include_once(LANGUAGE_DIR . $language . '.php');

  //загружаем файл шаблона, начинаем вывод
  include_once(TEMPLATE_DIR . 'default.php');

?>
```

Файл русского языка:

```
<?php
  define('LANG_TITLE', 'Главная страница');
  define('LANG_H1', 'Добро пожаловать!');
  define('LANG_MESSAGE1', 'Рады приветствовать вас на нашем сайте.');
?>
```

Файл английского языка:

```
<?php
  define('LANG_TITLE', 'Main page');
  define('LANG_H1', 'Welcome!');
  define('LANG_MESSAGE1', 'Welcome to our site.');
?>
```

Файл шаблона:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=LANG_TITLE?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?=LANG_H1?></h1>
    <p>
        <?=LANG_MESSAGE1?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Просто нужно поместить в $language имя файла языка, для удобства без расширения. Следует еще предусмотреть вывод страницы на дефолтном языке, если в $language ничего не присвоено. Вот, такова идея. Если что не ясно, пишите! Удачного дня :)

Comment: Уважаемый Roman Jertovsky спасибо огромное  можно ваш номер ICQ у меня некоторые вопросы

Comment: Если можно подробнее в какой директории создать файл для перевода и всякое

Answer (score 4):

```
где-то прописан массив $lang:
$lang['rus']['title'] = 'заголовок';
$lang['rus']['title_val'] = 'значение';
...
$lang['eng']['title'] = 'title';
$lang['eng']['title_val'] = 'title value';
...

задается язык пользователя:
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'rus';

и где-то на странице присутствует запись навроде такой:
<?=$lang[$_SESSION['lang']]['title']?>: <?=$lang[$_SESSION['lang']]['title_val']?>
```

Вот примерно так все и работает. Языковой массив можно прописать в файле и потом подключать его, а можно и хранить в БД. Ну, и нужна поправка на синтаксис шаблонизатора, если вы его используете.

Comment: Или распихать по разным файлам, например rus.php, eng.php, тогда массивы потеряют один из индексов меньше.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно написали про файлы-конфиги.
Устанавливаешь в них константы или задаешь массив.

Какой язык установлен в браузере по-умолчанию, можно узнать так

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php

либо самостоятельно разбираешь $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

Answer (score 1):

Слушайте. Я когда-то давно писал функцию переводчика с [translate.google.ru](http://translate.google.ru). Конечно, было давно и исходника у меня не осталось, но вам идею подам не с одним языком работать  - почти со всеми. Типа, допустим, определили вы используемый браузером язык и поместили в переменную $lang (пусть будет ru-ru), исходный текст на английском, а теперь смотрите:

```
$input = "Hello World";
$output = translate($input, $lang);

echo $output; // Привет Мир
```

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то странный вопрос - в чем проблема то переводишь и отдаешь посетителю, в зависимости от его настроек.

Самое тривиальное:
Все используемые слова лежат в таблице, в базе или в конфиг-файле. Каждый файл или таблица соответствует одному языку. Движок, в зависимости от настроек, собирает страничку используя ключевые слова из нужной таблицы (файла).

Comment: Наверно для вас ничего сложного, но я не профи первый раз делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь json конфигами они самые быстро обрабатываемые (ну или похожими конфигами, забыл название, но их труднее редактировать).